# Carastan substitute?

Tags: beer, ingredients, malt, specialty-malt, substitution

I recently brewed a recipe that called for Carastan malt. My LHBS didn't carry it, so I just used 40 L Crystal. In the finished beer, I'm missing the toffee and toastiness found in the original. Does anyone know of a better substitute? If there aren't really any good substitutes, where is a good place that I can find it online?

Comment: Out of curiosity what beer are you brewing, because I rarely see anyone talking about carastan malt.

Comment: Dead Guy Ale clone (extract + specialty grain) from BYO. It turned out OK, but definitely not exact. For only being my 2nd batch, I'm happy. I'm also currently force-carbing a Two-Hearted Ale clone and have a Newcastle clone in primary. My next batch will be my first AG, so hopefully it goes well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crystal 15L would have been a closer sub I think, even though the carastan is around 30-35L. I don't think there is a real good substitute for it.  There aren't a lot of malts like it, and I don't see too many people use it.  I put it in an [Ordinary Bitter](http://www.brew-dudes.com/carastan-english-bitter/828) last year and it does have a nice toffee aroma to it.

A combo of C15 and some special roast might get you in the ball park.
C40L is more caramel than toffee to me.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK you can buy Carastan in homebrew shops. The main supplier seems to be Baird's malt :

http://www.bairds-malt.co.uk/Roasted.html

I haven't seen it for sale online though (I will keep looking since I am also after some).